# Setting a boolean false value over REST API only works in JSON

Tags: rest, symfony, boolean

I am using FOSRestBundle and standard Symfony2 form functionalities to build a REST API.

I have a form definition like this:

```
$builder->add('paid', 'checkbox', array(
    'required' => false,
))
```

By sending data over the REST API in JSON format with a PATCH request I can successfully switch the data between true and false:

```
{
    "paid": true
}
```

respectively

```
{
    "paid": false
}
```

However, if the data is sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then I can only set the data to true, not to false.

This works: `paid=1` - a record with `paid=false` is set to `paid=true`.
This is ignored: `paid=0` - a record with `paid=true` remains `paid=true`.

I already considered using a choice type instead of checkbox (which worked in a test run), but this seems not to be the proper way to go.

What could I try to make it work correctly?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

you have o use callback to verify if checkbox is not checked and set it to false. I think you have a default value as true. Can you post you entity?

Comment: The default value is `false`. If the checkbox is not set, I don't want it to be set to false, but to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

use ChoiceType instead of Checkbox

```
->add('notificationNews', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array(
        '0' => false,
        '1' => true,
        'null' => null,
     ),
     'required' => false,
))
```